# How to set maximum table height by the height of another element

Tags: html, css

I'need to create a set of elements that will add and remove rows to a table. I haven't added any of the JS logic, yet. I just want to nail the look.
Here is a Pure HTML example that I've got so far, of what I want.

For styling I'm just using Bootstrap 5.

```
                    <div class = row>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">

                            <div class = row>
                                <div class = "col-lg-6">

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="the_select" class="form-label">Variable Name</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" id="the_select">
                                            <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                                            <option value="One">One</option>
                                            <option value="Two">Two</option>
                                            <option value="Three">Three</option>
                                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                          </select>
                                      </div>                                            

                                      <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="the_value_field" class="form-label">Value For Variable</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="the_value_field">
                                      </div>                                            

                                      <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="custom_field" class="form-label">Custom Field</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="custom_field">
                                      </div>                 
                                      
                                      <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Key-Value Pair</button>

                                </div>
                                <div class = "col-lg-6">



                                    <table class="table table-hover" style="max-height: 100%;">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th scope="col">Key</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Value</th>
                                            </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td>Name 1</td>
                                               <td>Value 1</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td>Name 1</td>
                                               <td>Value 1</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td>Name 1</td>
                                               <td>Value 1</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td>Name 1</td>
                                               <td>Value 1</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td>Name 1</td>
                                               <td>Value 1</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Name 1</td>
                                                <td>Value 1</td>
                                             </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                          </tbody>
                                    </table>   
                                    
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Remove Selected</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
```

What I want is to set the height of the table such that it's height is the same as the column  to it's left. So if any more elements are added to the table the scroll will be enabled but it's height will never be more than the summed height two inputs, the select and the button. I guess the labels factor in there as well.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is wrap the column and the table in a `div` (you could probably use `.row`), set the height you want on this wrapper (in a fixed value), then give the table the following styles:

```
table {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This of course will break you layout when the bootstrap columns collapse at smaller widths.  Best to put it in a media query.

Comment: I specifically want to avoid fix heights as there is no good value for it. Could you please tell me what a media query is?